# Proof of trigonometric ratios

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos A=\tan B$, $\cos B=\tan C$ and $\cos C=\tan A$ then prove that $$\sin A=\sin B=\sin C.$$

I have proven that $\sin A=\sin B$ but what is next?

Comment: The symmetry of the problem then ensures the rest

Comment: See $\#13$ of https://goo.gl/bsA0HR